# Loop Infinito, WHILE dentro de um FOR

Tags: php, pdo, loop, for, while

### Olá, como estão todos?

---

Estou tendo um problema com **LOOP INFINITO**, meu problema vem de um **FOR** que dentro dele eu passo um **WHILE**, pode ser questão de lógica ou realmente erro no código, segue o exemplo.

Eu possuo uma tabela chamada **OPTIONS** no meu banco **MySQL**, dentro dessa tabela, tenho os seguintes campos: *poll_id, id, candidate, votes*. minha intenção é trazer os candidatos cadastrados, junto com seus votos, minha função que vai fazer isso, está escrita assim.

```
public function resultsPoll()
{
    global $tpl;

    $recvTitle = "SELECT id, title, date, active FROM polls WHERE active = 1";
    $conn = connection::prepare($recvTitle);
    $conn->execute();
    $res = $conn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $id = $res->id;

    $sql = "SELECT votes, candidate FROM options WHERE poll_id = $id ORDER BY votes ASC";
    $stmt = connection::prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $options[]  = $result['candidate'];
        $votes[]    = $result['votes'];
    }

    $count = count($options);
    $amount = array_sum($votes);

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
    {
        $countVotes = $votes[$i] / $amount;

        while($i < $count)
        {
            $tplTemp = '
                <div class="col-12 opcoes">
                    <h4>' . $options[$i] . '</h4>
                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: ' . number_format($countVotes * 100) . '%"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
        }

    }

    $tpl->set("showResults", $tplTemp);
    unset($tplTemp);
}
```

Qual seria a forma mas correta de passar essa solicitação e receber todas as opções? Se eu remover esse WHILE, vou trazer apenas um valor do banco, mas não é o que preciso.

Comment: Acho que no lugar do `while` vc deveria usar outro `for`, pq vc vai precisar de outra variável de controle para comparar com a variável `$count`.

Comment: Olá @Sam, boa tarde! Com outro `FOR`, ele continua listando apenas um valor, mas muito obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @Sam, realmente eu não concatenei a variável, completa falta de atenção minha, um PONTO, mudou completamente a estrutura do código, agradeço pela contribuição.
Obrigado pela orientação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo visto você não precisa de um segundo loop dentro do `for`. Basta percorrer a array `$options` como está fazendo, e faltou concatenar a variável `$tplTemp` a cada volta do laço. Da forma que está fazendo, você está sobrescrevendo o valor dessa variável a cada volta do laço, resultando após a finalização no último valor atribuído.

Para concatenar é preciso adicionar o ponto antes do sinal `=`:

```
    AQUI CONCATENA
         ↓
$tplTemp .= '
    <div class="col-12 opcoes">
        <h4>' . $options[$i] . '</h4>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: ' . number_format($countVotes * 100) . '%"></div>
        </div>
    </div>';
```

Declare a variável `$tplTemp` antes também.

Então seu código ficaria desta forma:

```
$tplTemp;
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
  $countVotes = $votes[$i] / $amount;

   $tplTemp .= '
       <div class="col-12 opcoes">
           <h4>' . $options[$i] . '</h4>
           <div class="progress">
               <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: ' . number_format($countVotes * 100) . '%"></div>
           </div>
       </div>';
}
```